# Android DatePicker update needed for year calendar issues

Tags: android, datepicker, android-calendar, android-datepicker

When I go into my Android, app, and then go to add a new date, I get this screen first:
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cLjC.png)

The left side opens automatically to Dec 31 (today's date), and the right side shows December 2016.

If I then scroll on the left side from December to January, this happens (the right side calendar "advances" backwards to Jan 2016 instead of 2017:

[image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCO6M.png)

Comment: @rmando Trujillo what happens if you do it in the other way around ? from dec > nov > ... jan then still its 2016 or 2015 Jan?

Comment: Check there is similler code like this **setMaxDate** `datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());` If you have you need to remove it to select a future date